# How to read PowerShell script stdout and stderr from C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell

I'm implementing a custom PowerShell host and I need to read stdout and stderr of the PowerShell script. Problem is that I do not get stdout when I convert object returned by invoking pipeline to string. However, when I add "out-string" cmdlet to the pipeline it works perfectly fine. Is there any way to fetch stdout and stderror without using "out-string"?

```
this.currentPowerShell.AddScript(cmd);
Collection<PSObject> results = this.currentPowerShell.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
      Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
}
```

When I use the code above I only get partial stdout.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the output you currently get and what you are expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell's `stdout` output to another exe is synthesized by taking objects and projecting a string view of them.  PowerShell's native output is a stream of objects.  If you want to a string version of those objects then use `Out-String`.  However, from a C# perspective it is often more useful to deal directly with the objects that PowerShell outputs.

For `stderr`, you can read ErrorRecords from the `PowerShell.Streams.Error` property.  If you want a human readable string for those as well, run them thru Out-String before outputting to your user.