# Calling dll from c# code using powershell script not working

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using System.Management.Automation.dll to execute powershell script from c# code.

Following is my c# code

```
public void Execute()
        {
            using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                try
                {
                    var script = File.ReadAllText("script.ps1");
                    runspace.Open();
                    var ps = PowerShell.Create();
                    ps.Runspace = runspace;
                    ps.Commands.AddScript(script);
                    //ps.Ad
                    ps.Invoke();

                    foreach (var result in ps.Invoke())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

powershell script is

```
logparser "SELECT top 1 *,null INTO iisLogs FROM 'D:\u_ex200621\*.log' where date >= '2020-01-01' " -i:iisw3c -o:SQL -server:172.29.182.160 -database:DBA_Work -username:azuredev -password:cybage@123 -transactionRowCount:10000 -createTable: OFF
```

I have added logparser.dll path to Environment Variable so I can execute it from anywhere on machine.

But I tried to execute above code it did not execute anything.Same script I tried using Power shell then it works perfectly.

Please let me know correct way to execute powershell script using C# code.I tried multiple solutions on stackoverflow but no luck.

Comment: Where is "script.ps1" located?  Is it in the same folder and the c# executable?   Use full path name of the script file.

Comment: Yes,It is in same folder.

Comment: Thanks, It worked.I tried many solutions but didn't tried this running VS in admin. you saved my day.

Comment: Running the exe outside of VS will also work.

Comment: Hi, I installed windows service on server and there it is again not running. I change execution policy to unrestricted but no luck.Can you please me

Comment: When you install a service you have to it run As Admin.  go to Control panel and set service to As Admin by right clicking on service : Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools

Comment: I didnot find options there

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263901/how-to-run-a-program-from-windows-service-with-administrator-privileges

Comment: I did that but still it not executing powershell command. I tried same code using Console Application with Run As Admin.It is executing powershell script.

Comment: Are you getting a standard error output?  See following code which is different from your code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635541/how-to-read-powershell-script-stdout-and-stderr-from-c-sharp

Comment: No,I am not getting any error it did not execute script.If it execute script then I will get output.I install windows service on my local machine here it working fine.I think there is environment issue

Comment: Did yo use the differences in your code and the link i provided.  Looks like a collection is being returned not a singleton : Collection<PSObject> results = this.currentPowerShell.Invoke();

Comment: Actually in my code I am parsing result set also and writing it to text file,                                                     foreach (var result in ps.Invoke())
{
            Console.WriteLine(result);
}

Comment: The write line is automatically convert result to result.ToString();  The example code is casting to PSObject while your code is not.

Comment: Hi, I added logparser dll path to user path variable and service is running in different user context.So I added logparser.dll path to System Variable environmental and it started working. Thanks for you help.

Comment: It was my first comment to use full path.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng for your help.